# Calculate Power Dissipation of an IC

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, dissipation

I am trying to calculate power dissipation of the IC for thermal analysis of the PCB. I have calculated the power consumption but not sure which current values to be considered for calculating power dissipation of particular IC.

- Power Consumption = Vcc * Icc

Need help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What kind of IC is it? Also, check the datasheet too, it'll give an idea about power dissipation.

Comment: Consumption is usually dissipation unless there are external loads that might reduce the dissipation in the chip.

Comment: I am trying to calculate dissipation for LM2907. Datasheet says max power dissipation is 1200mW. But my Vcc is typical 24V.

Comment: *max power dissipation is 1200mW* That is a **maximum rating** and means that if you dissipate more than 1200 mW, the IC might be damaged. It is **not** related to the **actual** power usage. The **actual** power usage is simply: power going into the IC - power coming out of the IC. That power difference is what the IC dissipates. It depends on how you're actually using the IC what those numbers will be. Include your schematic and explain how you're using the IC.

Comment: For thermal analysys under maximum known ambient temperatures you will be looking at maximum power dissipation. This will depend on your IC thermal dissipation characteristics and its case etc. The datasheet will specifiy thermal characteristics in Celcius/W which you can use to calculate a maximum to ensure you don't exceed for a given ambient temperature.